# Avoid #VALUE! on empty cells when using GOOGLETRANSLATE function

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-translate

The idea is to enter a date in USA format (MM/DD) and it will automatically show the day of the week in spanish in another cell using code =googletranslate(TEXT(B9, "dddd"),"en", "es")

The thing is that empty cells are showing #VALUE!. How do I avoid this?

When using code =TEXT(B15, "dddd"), that doesnt happen, but it shows day of the week in english.
Because im using googlesheets, using code =TEXT(B22, "[$-0C0A]dddd") doesnt work to translate language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(B9="","", googletranslate(TEXT(B9, "dddd"),"en", "es"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.